# email exception with mime_header_check - POSTFIX

Tags: linux, postfix

I have configured the mime_header_check file so that emails containing compressed files do not reach my officials.
The problem is that I need compressed files to arrive in my email.
How could I configure for the mime_header_check to make an exception with my email account?

I use postfix as mail server

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to incorporate some sort of external content inspection to do that.

From postfix.org

> Header/body checks cannot depend on the recipient of a message.

There may be a way around it like using REDIRECT to direct all mail with compressed attachments to a certain mailbox that you have access to, but even if that works I don't think that's a good policy from a privacy standpoint.